# How to keep a set of commands in history?

Tags: zsh, command-history

There are a handful of commands which I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to lookup.

In some cases it makes sense to put them into aliases/shell scripts, 
however for commands that typically need some adjusting - this isn't practical (involved ssh/git commands for example).

Is there a way to load in commands on top of regular history *(which may have a limited length)*. So I can clear history, keeping useful commands always accessible from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> search?

Is there a function to prepend history or load in history from a separate file that is never written to?

---

*I realize this may seem obscure, however very occasionally I loose my history (it becomes corrupt or gets overwritten somehow), and I end up loosing handy commands I only use occasionally. While I can keep a backup, I'd rather be clearing history every so often - and keeping handy commands in a separate file.*

Comment: I would instead recommend defining several zsh functions in your `~/.zshrc`

Comment: I do this already, as noted in the question, some commands need edits on each use - so don't make much sense to wrap into an alias/function/script. While they could take arguments, this means I'm writing my own commands with their own argument syntax - which is too much overhead for my taste. Said differently, there are times when I'd rather use history search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With zsh, you can add history entries to the current history, from a file, using

```
fc -R yourfile
```

You can add `-I` to only load entries which aren’t already present.

`fc -W` can be used to write history to a file. See `man zshbuiltins` or [the online manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-fc) for details.